# Convert group count from activerecord into hash with multiple group stages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to get some statistics.

```
Model.where(status:@statuses).group(:sub_group, :status).count
```

This returns me

```
{
  ["sub_group1", "status1"] => 3},
  ["sub_group2", "status3"] => 7,
  ["sub_group1", "status2"] => 5, ....etc }
```

I want to merge them so each element has a unique subgroup.

e.g. a hash like:

```
{
  "sub_group1" => {"status1" => 3, "status2" => 5,
  "sub_group2" => {"status3" => 7},
}
```

or an array

```
[
  ["subgroup1", {"status1" = 3, "status2" => 5}],
  ["subgroup2".....

]
```

i.e. I want all those terms to be merged with sub_group as the primary header so that I can get the results for subgroup in one item.

Brain not working today....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `merge!`:

```
result = Model.where(status: @statuses).group(:sub_group, :status).count

result.reduce({}) do |collection, (attributes, count)| 
  collection.merge!(attributes[0] => { attributes[1] => count }) do |_, prev_value, next_value| 
    prev_value.merge!(next_value)
  end
end
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/C9bI/1)

Comment: Would be nice to have an explanation about the code. Also, what about a 3-level group clause?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
res = Model.where(status:@statuses).group(:sub_group, :status).count
nice_hash = {}
res.each do |key, count|
  nice_hash[key[0]] = {} unless nice_hash[key[0]]
  nice_hash[key[0]][key] = count
end
```

After this `nice_hash` should be on the desired format

Comment: No it won't, the result from a grouped count is a hash as described in the question.

Comment: my bad. Thanks for pointing that out. Deleting the comment now

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code.

```
a = Model.where(status:@statuses).group(:sub_group, :status).count
res = {}
    a.each do |k,v|
      c={}
      if res.has_key?(k[0])
        c[k[1]]=v
        res[k[0]]=res[k[0]].merge(c)
      else
        c[k[1]]=v
        res[k[0]]=c
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your question should be this or this should guide in the right direction:

```
Model.where(status:@statuses).group_by(&:sub_group)
```

If you need the only the statuses as you mentioned, you could do:

```
Model.where(status:@statuses).select(:status, :sub_group).group_by(&:sub_group)
```